# can't execute function in getJson

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm just beginning to learn jQuery, but I'm stuck at the beginning.

I am not able to execute any function in getJson. I tried to write seperate function to execute, but it didn't work, so now I tried to execute simplest possible code but I still can't make it work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="displayed_data">
  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.getJSON("http://ks3353689.kimsufi.com:5000/v1/closest_point?lng=19.0&lat=50",
      function(data){
        alert("test");
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `http://ks3353689.kimsufi.com:5000` page doesn't set the necessary CORS headers.

So you're facing the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) : you can't read that page in JavaScript from another origin.

I recommend this documentation on how to set the CORS headers for many languages : [enable-cors.org](http://enable-cors.org/)

As you're using Apache, you may directly read [this page](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html) :

> To expose the header, you simply add the following line inside either
>   the `<Directory>`, `<Location>`, `<Files>` or `<VirtualHost>` sections of your
>   server config (usually located in a *.conf file, such as httpd.conf or
>   apache.conf), or within a .htaccess file:
>
> `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

Comment: Well, OP would have used the best practice to use a relative URL, if it was on the same domain.

Comment: @WesleyMurch same-domain requests normally don't use absolute URLs. I think it's a safe bet.

Comment: @WesleyMurch nothing is for sure. The URL could just as well not exist, or the port could be closed, or the firewall could have had a bad day, or maybe a very unlucky particle stream keeps killing the relevant packets... That being said, adding a logging `fail` callback could help determining if it's CORS, 404 or connection timeout.

Comment: @dystroy I was accessing the website from different domain. (my personal computer, while script is hosted on a remote server god knows where...)

Comment: Just to be sure there is no confusion : the different origins we're talking about are the origin of the calling page (the one with the script) and the origin of the called page (your `kimsufi.com:5000` page).